# Why does Emacs.app (on Mac OS X) find the ctags executable inside Xcode.app?

Tags: osx, path

When I try to generate a `TAGS` file, emacs executes `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ctags`, which causes problems because it is not compatible with the settings emacs uses.

I figured out how to work around the issue by modifying `exec-path`, but I'm still confused about why it found that path in the first place. The Xcode path was not part of `exec-path` prior to my modification. The Xcode path is not included in $PATH at any time that I'm aware of. As far as I can tell there aren't any symlinks involved.

I'm running Emacs 24.5 on Mac OS 10.10.3.

Comment: I don't know, but suspect that `/usr/bin/ctags` is nothing but a wrapper to run the one inside the Xcode bundle. One reason I believe this, is the fact that a great many developer oriented programs in `/usr/bin` are exactly the same length: 14160 bytes. (Addendum: `execsnoop` disagrees, but maybe Apple has ways to fool dtrace sometimes.)

Comment: You can tell which ctags you're using by passing it the `--version` argument. The GNU Emacs versions says so, as does Exuberant Ctags (which I invariably use instead). I imagine whatever Xcode is using would provide some similar output.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has builtin `etags` ant its portable, on MacOS there are a default one: `ctags` at `/usr/bin/ctags` (but it is not *exuberant*). Emacs 
accepts `etags` generated TAG file, on other side `ctags` *exuberant* or not, you can add `-e` option to let `ctags` to generate the TAG file that Emacs can accept.

When the Emacs accepted TAG file had been generated, you can add it to Emacs' `tags-table-list`, not the `exec-path`:

```
(add-to-list 'tags-table-list tags-dir t #'string=)
```

> tags-table-list is a variable defined in ‘etags.el’.
>
> Its value is
>   ("~/.emacs.d/.tags/home/g_25.3.1/" "~/.emacs.d/.tags/source/g_25.3.1/" "~/.emacs.d/.tags/c/g_25.3.1/" "~/.emacs.d/.tags/os/g_25.3.1/")
>
> Documentation:
>   List of file names of tags tables to search.
>   An element that is a directory means the file "TAGS" in that directory.
>   To switch to a new list of tags tables, setting this variable is sufficient.
>   If you set this variable, do not also set ‘tags-file-name’.
>   Use the ‘etags’ program to make a tags table file.

There are a working example at [more reasonable Emacs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junjiemars/.emacs.d/master/config/tags.el)

```
(defun make-tags (home tags-file file-filter dir-filter &optional renew)
    "Make tags."
    (when (file-exists-p home)
        (let ((tags-dir (file-name-directory tags-file)))
            (if (file-exists-p tags-file)
                    (when renew (delete-file tags-file))
                (when (not (file-exists-p tags-dir))
                    (make-directory tags-dir t)))
            (dir-iterate home
                                     file-filter
                                     dir-filter
                                     (lambda (f)
                                         (eshell-command
                                            (format "etags -o %s -l auto -a %s ; echo %s"
                                                            tags-file f f))))
            (when (file-exists-p tags-file)
                (add-to-list 'tags-table-list tags-dir t #'string=)))))


(defun make-emacs-home-tags (tags-file &optional renew)
    "Make TAGS-FILE for Emacs' home directory."
    (let ((lisp-ff (lambda (f _) (string-match "\\\.el$" f)))
                (home-df
                 (lambda (d _)
                     (not
                        (string-match
                         "^\\\..*/$\\|^theme/$\\|^g_.*/$\\|^t_.*/$\\|^private/$" d)))))
        (make-tags emacs-home tags-file lisp-ff home-df renew)))
```

`make-tags` function need `dir-iterate` function to iterate directories:

```
(defun dir-iterate (dir ff df fn)
    "Iterating DIR, if FILE-FILTER return T then call FN, 
and if DIR-FILTER return T then iterate into deeper DIR.

     (defun FILE-FILTER (file-name absolute-name))
     (defun DIR-FILTER (dir-name absolute-name))

\(FN DIR FILE-FILTER DIR-FILTER FN\)"
    (dolist (f (file-name-all-completions "" dir))
        (unless (member f '("./" "../"))
            (let ((a (expand-file-name f dir)))
                (if (directory-name-p f)
                        (when (and df (funcall df f a)
                                             (dir-iterate a ff df fn)))
                    (when (and ff (funcall ff f a)
                                         (funcall fn a))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Emacs will install a command line program `etags` which could be used by manually running cli `find -name *.c | etags -`.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Create-Tags-Table.html#Create-Tags-Table

So it has nothing to do with Emacs in this case. It's XCode installer who changed the link destination of "/usr/bin/ctags".

Solution 1:
Change the link back by `sudo ln -s /where-the-ctags-exists/ctags /usr/bin/ctags`.

Solution 2:
Modify the environment variable PATH instead. Insert below code into ~/.bash_profile,

export path=/where-the-ctags-exists:$PATH

Comment: I agree it has nothing to do with Emacs in this case. After reading Harald's comment to my question, and doing some experiments, it is clear that `/usr/bin/ctags` is executing the one in the Xcode bundle. However, I don't understand what you mean by link, or how to change it back. `ls -l /usr/bin/ctags` returns `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14160 Sep 29  2014 /usr/bin/ctags`. As far as I can tell, it's not a link. How would I change it back?

Comment: What emacs add on u use

Comment: (So this popped to the top, I suppose because no answer has been accepted.) You can't just go and change stuff in `/usr/bin` on recent versions of OS X, because of [system integrity protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). In any case, a better way to override an OS supplied binary is to put overriding binaries in a different directory and then adding that to the front of the path.

Comment: Is there some variable that can be used to specify what command is executed when Emacs runs ctags? If so, it should be easy to customize it so it points to the correct executable.

Comment: @Jay, you can `sudo rm /usr/bin/ctags` before `sudo ln -s /path/of/latest/ctags /usr/bin/ctags.